# Removing a dictionary from a list of dictionaries to avoid a divide by zero error

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries for example:

```
[{'askPrice': '0.06671700',
  'askQty': '20.50280000',
  'bidPrice': '0.06671600',
  'bidQty': '11.01110000',
  'symbol': 'ETHBTC'},
 {'askPrice': '0.00237300',
  'askQty': '34.35000000',
  'bidPrice': '0.00237200',
  'bidQty': '33.33300000',
  'symbol': 'LTCBTC'},
 {'askPrice': '0.00000000',
  'askQty': '0.00000000',
  'bidPrice': '0.00000000',
  'bidQty': '0.00000000',
  'symbol': 'BCCBTC'}]
```

The third dictionary in the list with `'symbol':'BCCBTC'` has `'askPrice': '0.00000000'`
so when I try to divide the askPrice by zero I get the divide by zero error. How do I remove this entire dictionary -

```
{'askPrice': '0.00000000',
 'askQty': '0.00000000',
 'bidPrice': '0.00000000',
 'bidQty': '0.00000000',
 'symbol': 'BCCBTC'}
```

from the list of dictionaries? Or even better how do I remove all dictionaries that have an `askPrice` or `bidPric`e of `0` from the list of dictionaries regardless of what the `symbol` is.

Comment: Use a simple loop...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your data using a list comprehension, checking whether the `float` converted `bidPrice` or `askPrice` values are not 0:

```py
[d for d in data if float(d['askPrice']) != 0 and float(d['bidPrice']) != 0]
```

Output:

```
[
 {'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'bidPrice': '0.06671600', 'bidQty': '11.01110000', 'askPrice': '0.06671700', 'askQty': '20.50280000'},
 {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'bidPrice': '0.00237200', 'bidQty': '33.33300000', 'askPrice': '0.00237300', 'askQty': '34.35000000'}
]
```

Comment: OP asked for "*or*" for both the values being `0`. `float(d['askPrice']) != 0 or float(d['bidPrice'])`

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan OP wants to *remove* entries where either value is `0`, so they want to keep values where both are non-zero